# Jlabel created from a template method pattern doesn't appear on application

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am working on MVC and design pattern, so I am trying to put them all together to an application that creates JLabels dynamically and handles label text, fonts, alignment and color. As I conceived it, there is a Template that sets text, font, color and alignment to the label. I am using the template pattern here and the code goes like this

```
    import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

  public abstract class labelTemplate{
    JLabel abstractJLabel = new JLabel();
    textAlignmentView textAlignmentViewObject = new textAlignmentView();

    public final void createLabel(){
        setLabelText();
        setLabelFont();
        setLabelColor();
        setLabelAlignment();
        addLabelToContainer();
    }

    //all by-default values
    public void setLabelText(){
        abstractJLabel.setText(" ");
    }

    public void setLabelFont(){
        Font abstractLabelFont = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        abstractJLabel.setFont(abstractLabelFont);
    }

    public void setLabelColor(){
        abstractJLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    }

    public void setLabelAlignment(){
        abstractJLabel.setAlignmentX(Label.LEFT);
        abstractJLabel.setAlignmentY(Label.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    }

    public void addLabelToContainer(){
        textAlignmentViewObject.addJLabelToContainer(abstractJLabel);
    }

}
```

Now, there is a class that extends the template above

```
import java.awt.Font;

public class boldTextLeftAlignmentLabel extends labelTemplate{

    //constructor
    public boldTextLeftAlignmentLabel(){}

    @Override
    public void setLabelText(){
        abstractJLabel.setText("Έντονο κείμενο αριστερή στοίχηση");
    }

    @Override
    public void setLabelFont(){
        Font abstractLabelFont = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);
        abstractJLabel.setFont(abstractLabelFont);
    }
}
```

I am creating Model, View and Controller classes and I put a  boldTextLeftAlignmentLabel label in the controller

Model

```
public class textAlignmentModel {
    //nothing in here for now
}
```

View

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class textAlignmentView extends JFrame{
    Container textAlignmentViewContainer;

    public textAlignmentView(){
        super("Στοίχιση κειμένου");
        addContainerToTextAlignmentView();
        textAlignmentViewContainer.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }


    public void addJLabelToContainer(JLabel label){
        textAlignmentViewContainer.add(label);
        textAlignmentViewContainer.validate();
        textAlignmentViewContainer.repaint();
    }

    public void addContainerToTextAlignmentView(){
         textAlignmentViewContainer = getContentPane();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
public class textAlignmentController{

    textAlignmentModel textAlignmentModelObject = new textAlignmentModel();
    textAlignmentView textAlignmentViewObject = new textAlignmentView();

    public textAlignmentController(textAlignmentModel textAlignmentModelObj, textAlignmentView textAlignmentViewObj){
        textAlignmentModelObject = textAlignmentModelObj;
        textAlignmentViewObject = textAlignmentViewObj;

        //trying to create boldTextLeftAlignmentLabel label
        boldTextLeftAlignmentLabel label1 = new boldTextLeftAlignmentLabel();
        label1.createLabel();
    }
}
```

When I run the application

```
public class textAlignmentApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        textAlignmentView textAlignmentViewObject = new textAlignmentView();
        textAlignmentModel textAlignmentModelObject = new textAlignmentModel();
        textAlignmentController textAlignmentControllerObject = new textAlignmentController(textAlignmentModelObject, textAlignmentViewObject);

        textAlignmentViewObject.setVisible(true);
        textAlignmentViewObject.setSize(800, 600);
        textAlignmentViewObject.setDefaultCloseOperation(textAlignmentView.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I get no label at all. When I debug, I can see that label takes all the arguments. What am I doing wrong? I don't know how to search or ask for that. I cannot understand where is the problem. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: default LayoutManager for JFrame is BorderLayout, then you opnly to replace one JLabel with another, is it correct

Comment: Please follow the Java Naming Conventions: Class names should be in `UpperCamelCase` (then you can also omit this superfluous `...Object` suffix for the instances that you are creating!). Apart from that, the structure is rather confusing. Why is the "template" *inheriting* from `JFrame`?

Comment: @mKorbel I'm afraid nothing happened. I put the JLabel with BorderLayout and still I get nothing. Is there anything else that I must change?

Comment: @Marco13 the `extends JFrame` expression was from something else I tried and I forgot to delete it. It wasn't needed at all. As far as the naming convention's conserned, I am using namings as is for now, I am going to change it after solving the main problem. Thank you for your suggestions